# Closing a game window depending on a counter variable

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is create an int and when everytime I clicked yes in my confirmation dialog the int will increase by 1 and the whole program should stop executing when the number that store into that int reached to 5.

The code isn't working and nothing happens no matter how many times I click on the 'Yes' button from the confirmation dialog box, I am expecting it the code to stop when I click on the 'Yes' for 5 times.

I'm a beginner still trying to learn java , I have no clue what have I did wrong on my code because they seem logically correct, really appreciate if someone can give me a hand ! Thanks very much !

This is the main game

```
   public class Game {
        private JPanel Game;
        private JButton Water;
    private JButton Nature;
    private JButton Fire;
    private JLabel countDownLabel;
    private JLabel computerScore;
    private int myChoice;
    private int computerChoice;
            int gamePlayed = 0; //store the times of game played


public Game() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Elements");
    frame.setContentPane(this.Game);
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

if the times of game played is less than 5 times , execute the following code

```
               if (gamePlayed <= 5) {
                   Water.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
                   {
                       @Override
                       //Water counter Fire , Nature counter water
                       public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
                       {
                           int select;
                           select = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( null, "You're using the power of water", "Water", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION );

                           if ( select == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION )
                           {
                               myChoice = 0;
                               computerChoice = computerPlays();
                               conditionsDisplayResults( myChoice, computerChoice );
                               gamePlayed = gamePlayed + 1;//add 1 time of played game when the yes option clicked

                           }
                       }
                   } );
                   Fire.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
                   {
                       @Override
                       public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
                       {
                           int select = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( null, "You're using the power of fire", "Fire", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION );

                           if ( select == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION )
                           {
                               myChoice = 1;
                               computerChoice = computerPlays();
                               conditionsDisplayResults( myChoice, computerChoice );
                               gamePlayed += 1;//add 1 time of played game when the yes option clicked
                           }
                       }
                   } );
                   Nature.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
                   {
                       @Override
                       public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
                       {
                           int select = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( null, "You're using the power of nature", "Nature", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION );

                           if ( select == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION )
                           {
                               myChoice = 2;
                               computerChoice = computerPlays();
                               conditionsDisplayResults( myChoice, computerChoice );
                               gamePlayed += 1;//add 1 time of played game when the yes option clicked
                           }


                       }
                   } );
               }
```

else when the times of game played is more than 5 times , execute

```
   else{ //else which when the times of game played is more than 5 times , execute the following code

                   GameResult();
                   MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();

               } 
}
```

And what the GameResult() doing is System.exit(0) which exit the program

Comment: You say that it's "wrong," but you give no indication of what makes it wrong. How is your code supposed to behave? How is it actually behaving? Be as descriptive as possible because we can't give you an answer if we have to make assumptions or guesses.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, is it okay right now?

Comment: You did not really add any new information in your edit. Just re-arranged your text a bit. So no, it is not clearer.

Comment: I put some comments on my code too, can you tell me which part of my code you don't understand?

Comment: Generally speaking, if your question doesn't explain enough for us to know what we're looking for in your code, and your code is longer than just a few lines, then we aren't going to read the code to try to understand what you want to do. The premise of the question is that the code *doesn't* do what you want, so what you *do* want probably can't be inferred from the code; a clear explanation in text is necessary.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will edit it right now

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, you want the `gamePlayed` variable to count up to five and then for your program to stop.

The problem is that you are only testing `if (gamePlayed <= 5)` once in your code, in a place where `gamePlayed` is guaranteed to be zero. You are testing it before you add any event-listeners to the buttons, before the user has had a chance to click on them, and before `gamePlayed` can be incremented as a result of those clicks.

Incrementing `gamePlayed`, by itself, just increases its value by 1; it doesn't cause anything else to happen as a consequence. Since you want the game to stop when this number reaches 5, you need to test this condition `if (gamePlayed >= 5)` (note the greater-than, not less-than symbol) immediately after each time it is incremented.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually lack of a stop condition and not adding the listener correctly. The code for checking number of clicks should be inside the added anonymous ActionListener classes and added only once. Something close to this:

```
Water.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
                       {
                           @Override
                           //Water counter Fire , Nature counter water
                           public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
                           {
                               //check if game is over
                               int select;
                               select = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( null, "You're using the power of water", "Water", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION );

                               if ( select == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION )
                               {
                                   myChoice = 0;
                                   computerChoice = computerPlays();
                                   conditionsDisplayResults( myChoice, computerChoice );
                                   gamePlayed = gamePlayed + 1;//add 1 time of played game when the yes option clicked

                               }
                           }
                       } );
```

You should be doing the checks for whether the game has ended inside the listener for each button since the code is not running sequentially but is being triggered by events, in this case user clicks.